# Site Visits returns zero

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, site-usage

I am using CSOM to retreive data for SiteCollection Usage(SharePoint 2010 and 2013). My code is below:

```
            Site site = context.Site;
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(site);
            context.Load(site, s => s.Usage);
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(site.Usage.Storage);
            Console.WriteLine(site.Usage.Hits);
            Console.WriteLine(site.Usage.Visits);
            Console.WriteLine(site.Usage.StoragePercentageUsed);
```

Result:

```
Storage - 1345367
Hits - 0
Visits - 0
StoragePercentageUsed - 0
```

Hits, Visits are 0 for all site collections. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Check this if it helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6eef9e76-c0d5-458e-b6f5-091615bb9ba5/sharepoint-2013-usage-report-showing-0-record?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Also this http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/#.VtgFhyh96Ul